# How to connect a USB 2.0 9 pin cable to a USB 3.0 19 pin connector?

Tags: usb, motherboard

I have a multi-card reader that connects to my motherboard via USB 9/10 pin port, the problem is that I have none available, however I have a free 19/20 pin USB 3 port. I have been looking everywhere for an adapter to convert the 9 pin to 19 but I cannot find it anywhere... The only one I found is the other way around, 19 to 9.

Am I missing something? Like it's not possible to do the conversion or something?

Thanks!

EDIT: I don't want to just jam the 9 pin into the 19... I was looking more for an adapter/converter

Comment: Well I don't want to just jam the 9 pin into the 19... I was looking more for an adapter/converter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I accidentally found it... It seems to be much less common than 19 to 9... for whoever is interested this is what I was looking for.

[http://www.amazon.com/SIENOC-USB3-0-Female-Motherboard-Adapter/dp/B00O0HC3Y0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00O0HC3Y0)

[image]